# NSString apostrophe character

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

I've got a question regarding apostrophe character in NSString.

I'm receiving the json object from some web service and apostrophe character is represented there like '''.

Should I manually replace this character to the apostrophe one or it's possible perhaps to change the encoding of the string somehow and make the NSString to show it like '?

Thank you.

Comment: If it's only this web service doing that, it may just be safe to programmatically correct the `"` character to an apostrophe.  But of course you don't want to correct those quote characters that aren't supposed to be apostrophes.

Comment: are you getting the **ASCII code** i.e. **&#039;** or the character **'**

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the ASCII code &#039;. Might it be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one? just try to filter yourstring then log it.

```
yourString = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'''" withString:@""];
```